# Search keyword from HTTP response in #<Nokogiri::XML::Comment data

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I am using ruby to send a http request, and receive response. Now I need to search for a keyword in the response. I use Nokogiri::HTML(response.body) and following is the part of the http response that I want to look into for the keyword:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x0c24940 "\n\t<div style=\"float:left;margin-left:20px;width:200px;\">\n\t<p><strong>Check this</strong></p>\n\t<ul>\n\t\t<li><a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank'>example.com</a></li>\n\t\t<li><a href='http://www.example.com/hello' target='_blank'>example only</a></li>\n\t\t<li><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"window.open( '/path/to/example.xml', '', 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=800,width=1000,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no' );\">Example with Coffee</a></li>\n\t</ul>\n\n\t</div>\n">
```

Just to make clear, the http response has several other components in addition to above, like:

> `#<Nokogiri::XML::Text, ::Element`

and more `::Comments` etc, and each have different numeric IDs like 
`#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x0c24940`, `#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1e21321`, etc.

How can I retrieve the string '`Example with Coffee`' out of the http response using nokogiri?

**Update**
Adding part of HTML response as well:

```
#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x53a5ef4 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x53a0cb4 name="html">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x53112c8 name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x51e3f74 "\n\t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x52d2168 name="head" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x51c3738 "\n\t\t\n\t\t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x523dfa4 " These meta tags will prevent the browser from caching the page --!>\n\t\t<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>\n\t\t<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>\n\t\t<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>\n\n\t\t<!-- Stylesheets ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x51b9d3c " \n\t\t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x52ae0b2 name="link" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x52accc0 name="type" value="text/css">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x52s2cfc name="rel" value="stylesheet">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x52a1eb4 name="href" value="/styles/main.css">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5251b70 "\n\t\t">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5d59ed0 name="style" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x5c5ab20 name="type" value="text/css">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::CDATA:0x51eca30 "\n\t\t\tul li { margin-left: -20px; }\n\t\t\t#checkPage1 { \n\t\t\t\tdisplay: inline-block;\n\t\t\t\t*display: inline;\n\t\t\t\tborder: 1px solid #618CB3;\n\t\t\t\tbackground-color: #FEFEFE;\n\t\t\t\tpadding: 3px;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t
```

Here's the original HTML request & response:

```
>> uri = URI.parse("http://<1.2.3.4>/about/index.php")
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000008ee6760 URL:http://1.2.3.4/about/index.php>
>> http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
=> #<Net::HTTP 1.2.3.4 open=false>
>> request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
=> #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
>> request['Cookie'] = 'Fruits=12345'
=> "Fruits=12345"
>> response = http.request(request)
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
>> response.body
=> "<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t\n\t\t<!-- These meta tags will prevent the browser from caching the page --!>\n\t\t<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>\n\t\t<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>\n\t\t<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>\n\n\t\t<!-- Stylesheets --> \n\t\t<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/styles/main.css\">\n\t\t<style type=\"text/css\">\n\t\t\tul li { margin-left: -20px; }\n\t\t\t#licDiv { \n\t\t\t\tdisplay: inline-block;\n\t\t\t\t*display: inline;\n\t\t\t\tborder: 1px solid #6186B3;\n\t\t\t\tbackground-color: #FEFEFE;\n\t\t\t\tpadding: 3px;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t#licDiv p {\n\t\t\t\tmargin: 2px 0;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t.nobullets {\n\t\t\t\tpadding-left: 10;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t.nobullets li {\n\t\t\t\tlist-style: none;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t</style>\n\t\t\n\t\t<!-- Scripts -->\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/GlobalData.js\"></script>\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n\t\t\tfunction fn1() {\n\n\t\t\t\t// Disable Caching\n\t\t\t\t//$.ajaxSetup({cache: false}});\n\n\t\t\t\tif( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {\n\t\t\t\t\t// Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari\n\t\t\t\t\txmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\telse {\n\t\t\t\t\t// Code for IE6\n\t\t\t\t\txmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( \"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\" );\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\txmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {\n\t\t\t\t\tif( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcheck2 = xmlhttp.responseText;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif( 0 == check2 ) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\talert( \"msg1.\" );\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\telse {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\talert( \"Issue1.\" );\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\txmlhttp.open( \"GET\", \"page1.php\", true );\n\t\t\t\txmlhttp.send();\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t</script>\n\n\t</head>\n\t\n\t<body style=\"\">\n\n\t\t<!-- Page Title -->\n\t\t<div class=\"pageTitle\">\n\t\t\t<img src=\"/images/page_about.png\"/>\n\t\t\tAbout\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t<!-- The Main Area -->\n\t\t<div class=\"container\" style=\"height:700px;\">\n\n\t<p><strong>This is a big juicy \"apple\" (Fruit)</strong></p>\n\t<ul>\n<div style=\"float:left;margin-left:20px;width:200px;\">\n\t<p><strong>Helpful Links</strong></p>\n\t<ul>\n\t\t<li><a href='http://www.fruits.com' target='_blank'>Fruits.com</a></li>\n\t\t<li><a href='http://www.fruits.com/apple' target='_blank'>Apple Fruit</a></li>\n\t\t<li><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"window.open( '/manual/apple.xml', '', 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=800,width=1000,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no' );\">Example with Coffee</a></li>\n\t</ul>\n\n\t</div>\n-->\n\t<p style=\"clear:both;\">
```

**HTML Page Source**

> http://pastie.org/8020148#10

Comment: could you give me the `html` code?

Comment: it is huge. Is it ok if I give a part of http response?

Comment: yes,at least the code you have..

Comment: @Priti I've added a part of http response in the post above.

Comment: do one thing write down in top of your code `require pp`. then print the result what you pasted here as with `pp` .

Comment: Okay doing with pp now...

Comment: @Priti I double checked & found that the response remains the same as before...

Comment: I asked you to print the data in pretty printed way,so that we can see it properly. :)

Comment: @Priti ah okay..it is the same as one I posted in my post. Not sure if it would make any difference but I am doing all of this on irb prompt. Also, here's the same response I put on pastie for easy viewing - http://pastie.org/8016440

Comment: People are asking you for HTML, and you're giving them an object dump. If you want to make it easy for folks to answer your question, provide the relevant HTML snippets and your parsing code.

Comment: @MarkThomas Sorry, I've added the original http request & response above now. Please check.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something. The string starting with `#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document` is neither an HTTP response nor an HTML string. It is a Nokogiri object printed to the console. Can you please do a View Source of the page you are scraping, and copy the relevant HTML (pretty-printed) into your question?

Comment: @MarkThomas I understand now. I have posted the page source above.

Comment: Next question: How does one know to extract "Examples with Coffee" as opposed to the other similarly coded titles such as "Pineapples"? Do you want them all, or are you looking for one that contains a keyword?

Comment: @MarkThomas These values are standard in this HTTP response. For example, 'Example with Coffee' and 'Example with Fruits'. Then there is variable value like 'Version' which can change. So, I intend to be able to a) confirm standard value like 'Example with XXX' exist in http response, and b) capture variable value like 'Version: xxx' from the http response.

Comment: OK, that's new information that should have been in your question. Back to my question, given the sample HTML you provided, what are you looking for? The `<strong>` element containing the word "coffee"? All its sub-elements? Please provide an example of what you want to get out of it. You would have lots of answers by now if you just provided what people need to answer this question.